# strapi reset password alwasy call localhost

Tags: strapi

I configured template to use URL to send reset password email.

I alwasy got this email with link to localhost so on the server it does not work.

I checked the implementation and seems there this is no way to override it:

```
const url = `${getAbsoluteAdminUrl(
    strapi.config
  )}/auth/reset-password?code=${resetPasswordToken}`;
  return strapi
    .plugin('email')
    .service('email')
    .sendTemplatedEmail(
      {
        to: user.email,
        from: strapi.config.get('admin.forgotPassword.from'),
        replyTo: strapi.config.get('admin.forgotPassword.replyTo'),
      },
      strapi.config.get('admin.forgotPassword.emailTemplate'),
      {
        url,
        user: _.pick(user, ['email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'username']),
      }
    )
    .catch(err => {
      // log error server side but do not disclose it to the user to avoid leaking informations
      strapi.log.error(err);
    });
};
```

and

```
const getAbsoluteUrl = adminOrServer => (config, forAdminBuild = false) => {
  const { serverUrl, adminUrl } = getConfigUrls(config, forAdminBuild);
  let url = adminOrServer === 'server' ? serverUrl : adminUrl;

  if (url.startsWith('http')) {
    return url;
  }

  let hostname =
    config.get('environment') === 'development' &&
    ['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0'].includes(config.get('server.host'))
      ? 'localhost'
      : config.get('server.host');

      return `http://${hostname}:${config.get('server.port')}${url}`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The url can be set from the admin panel: General > Settings > Users & Permissions > Advanced settings > Reset password page.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-config-sync to sync this across your environments.